# Change UIView with button action

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

My First View (with the UIView and the button) will have a top menu where i want to be able to change views (show Red UIView, Blue UIView and so on)

My problem is, i don't want to add a Tab Bar Item for the Red and Blue view, i want them to be viewable only if the user click on the buttons on the menu, but i still want to show the Tab Bar if the user want to change, for example, from the Red view to the Second view.

Is this possible? I though about changing the UIView if the user click on the button but im not sure if this is the correct way.

Did someone tried to do something like this? Is there any better way?

I hope i was clear with my question but if its confusing please say so i can edit and find a better way to explain my problem.

Thanks.

[image: Storyboard Picture]

Comment: How about having navigation controller instead of your first view with button and keeping it as root view controller of it? You can then push red and blue views to it.

Comment: The problem is that if i push the red/blue view they'll hide the tab bar, thats why i thought about using a Container View, since i can limit were the view will appear, hence i'll not hide the Tab Bar.

Comment: They won't hide the tab bar I think, if the navigation controller itself has tabbar item, can you please try? (Your tabbar controller->(one tab)UINavigationController->Your main view.)

Comment: Sorry Sunil you were 100% right. This means i still don't know exactly how Navigation Controller works. I know im asking too much but if possible could you tell me why isnt the tab bar hidden when i change views using Navigation Controller? 

If you want to answer my question i'll gladly mark as correct.

Comment: UINavigationController and UITabBarControllers are different and independent of each-other. So you can use a navigation controller inside any of tabbar controller and use tabbar in any of the navigation controller's view. Playing with these controllers will explain it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having navigation controller instead of your first view with button and keeping it as root view controller of it? You can then push red and blue views to it.

Comment: Sunil like i said your answer was perfect. Now my only doubt is, if i show my views modally it will hide the tab bar, if i show with push everything works fine. But my problem is with memory, since i don't have a back button (because its a menu) is there a problem that the views will stack to a point where the app will freeze? I did a test with Memory Leak and everything seems fine. Thanks for doing a quick explain on the navigation controller.

Comment: You can just present the controller to UITabBarController and tabbar will be hidden. Also attach `dismiss` button to dismiss the controller when done.